# How to exclude columns within csv DictReader using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I really want to read the following csv file:
ID; First Name; Last Name; Phone;
123; Max; Smith; 0193849843
124; John; Doe; 0012943843

..and extract it into the following Format:

[OrderedDict([('ID', '123'), ('Last Name', 'Smith')]), OrderedDict([('ID', '124'), ("Last Name", "Doe")])]

However, with my Code displayed below, im only able to get the OrderedDict with all keys inside. How is it possible to only Access certain columns within the csv file?
I Need the exact Output in order to later transform the Code into JSON.

```
import csv

csvfilepath = r"csvpath"
jsonfilepath = r"jsonpath"

data = []

with open(csvfilepath) as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,delimiter=";")

    for csvRow in csvReader:
        ID = csvRow["ID"]
        data.append(csvRow)
```

Thanks a lot!
Jonas

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **yes**, you can read specific columns (but with a caveat).
However it's going to be much simpler if you just read all the columns and then build a dictionary from the columns that you need. It's much simpler and might even perform better.

You can use `fieldnames` argument to explictly define the columns you are interested in. The caveat is that the other columns will still be present in the dictionary under the `None` key (unless you provide another key with the `restkey` argument).

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

> The `fieldnames` parameter is a sequence. If `fieldnames` is omitted, the
>   values in the first row of file f will be used as the `fieldnames`.
>   Regardless of how the `fieldnames` are determined, the ordered
>   dictionary preserves their original ordering.
>
> If a row has more fields than `fieldnames`, the remaining data is put in
>   a list and stored with the fieldname specified by `restkey` (which
>   defaults to None). If a non-blank row has fewer fields than
>   `fieldnames`, the missing values are filled-in with `None`.

You can use `fieldnames` to specify the columns you want and then use `.pop` to remove the `None` key (and its values).

Consider the following file:

```
header1,header2
a,b
c,d
e,f
```

Then:

```
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=['header1'])
    print([row for row in csvReader])
    # [OrderedDict([('header1', 'header1'), (None, ['header2'])]),
    #  OrderedDict([('header1', 'a'), (None, ['b'])]),
    #  OrderedDict([('header1', 'c'), (None, ['d'])]), 
    #  OrderedDict([('header1', 'e'), (None, ['f'])])]
```

If we pop the `None` key:

```
csvReader = list(csvReader)
[row.pop(None) for row in csvReader]
# yes, abusing list comprehension for a side effect for sake of a simple example.
# Don't do that in production code
print([row for row in csvReader])
# [OrderedDict([('header1', 'header1')]), OrderedDict([('header1', 'a')]),
#  OrderedDict([('header1', 'c')]), OrderedDict([('header1', 'e')])]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. 
The only Thing is that my dict Looks as follows when I select the columns "ID" and "Last Name". As you can see Last Name does not match. Do you know why? 
Also, is there a way to exclude the first part of the dict containing only the headers? 
Output: [OrderedDict([('ID', 'ID'), ('Last Name', 'First Name')]), OrderedDict([('ID', '123'), ('Last Name', 'Max')]), OrderedDict([('ID', '124'), ('Last Name', 'John')])]. 
Thanks again!

Comment: @J.Weiser This has more to do with the format of the csv file you are trying to read than the code